# Display message on 2 * 16 character lcd using respberry pi 3 on system startup

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, iot, lcd

I have `raspberry pi 3 B`.

**Use case**: To print `ip address` and `time` to a `2 * 16 character lcd` display on system startup or reboot.

For this, I am using python code which is **working fine** when I am running from the terminal.

**Problem**: 
On system startup, nothing is getting displayed in lcd screen.

**Details**:

I tried three ways:

**way 1:**

I have added to `/etc/rc.local` the following lines

```
echo "Display ip to 2*16 char display from /etc/rc.local" >> /home/pi/Workspace/python/pi-screen/logs.log

sudo /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Workspace/python/pi-screen/src/display.py >> /home/pi/Workspace/python/pi-screen/logs-1.log
```

On system reboot it was expected that it should print to the `lcd display` but **it didn't.**

When I am running `display.py` from console using `python display.py` it's running file and printing to `2 * 16 characters lcd display` as expected.

**Way 2:**

I have even tried adding script to `/etc/init.d/lcd`.

when running using `/etc/init.d/lcd start` it worked but on system startup but it **didn't work** too.

**way 3:**

Using `.bashrc` **worked** (Not preferred )

I added the below line to `.bashrc` file and **it worked**.

```
#Show IP Address (temp solution)
/home/pi/Workspace/python/pi-screen/src/display.py
```

Adding to `.bashrc` is not preferred as it prints to lcd screen on every login.

`----------------------------------------------------------------------`

**Code used**:

**lcd init file** `/etc/init.d/lcd`

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: LCD - date / time / ip address
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Liquid Crystal Display
# Description: date / time / ip address
### END INIT INFO


#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/lcd


export HOME
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting LCD"
        /home/pi/Workspace/python/pi-screen/src/display.py  2>&1 &
    ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping LCD"
        LCD_PID=`ps auxwww | grep pi-screen | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
        kill -9 $LCD_PID
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/lcd {start|stop}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

**display.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import display_conf
import utils

lcd = display_conf.get_lcd()

def show_msg(msg, how_long):
    lcd.message(msg)
    time.sleep(how_long)
    lcd.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    now = utils.get_time()
    ip = utils.get_host_ip()
    msg = now + "\n" + ip

    show_msg(msg, 10)
```

**display_config.py**

```
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD

def get_lcd():
    # Raspberry Pi pin setup
    lcd_rs = 25
    lcd_en = 24
    lcd_d4 = 23
    lcd_d5 = 17
    lcd_d6 = 18
    lcd_d7 = 22
    lcd_backlight = 2

    # Define LCD column and row size for 16x2 LCD.
    lcd_columns = 16
    lcd_rows = 2

    lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight)

    return lcd
```

**utils.py**

```
import socket
import time

def get_host_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ip = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()

    return ip

def get_time():
    now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return now
```

**Note**: `/home/pi/Workspace/python/pi-screen/src/display.py` and `/etc/init.d/lcd` both have executable permission.

Answer (score 1):

To run python script via /etc/rc.local:

1) Edit the file using `sudo /etc/rc.local`;

2) Add the following to the file **right before** `exit 0`:

```
(sleep 5;python /home/pi/Workspace/python/pi-screen/src/display.py)&
```

The parentheses allows your to run multiple commands in the background. The `sleep 5` will delay the running of script by 5 seconds, as some of the services that your script depend on may not be available yet at the time of booting rc.local.

Alternatively you can use crontab `@reboot` to automate the execution of your script.

Using crontab:

1) run command line `sudo crontab -e`;

2) add the command to the end of the file:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Workspace/python/pi-screen/src/display.py
```

Answer (score -1):

simple code don't take tension its to easy 
1. connection properly http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-lcd-set-up-and-programming-in-python/  using this link help 
2. follow all instruction which written in this page 
3. use this code

```
import time
import datetime
from RPLCD.gpio import CharLCD
from RPi import GPIO
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
lcd = CharLCD(numbering_mode=GPIO.BCM, pin_rs=22, pin_rw=24, pin_e=23, pins_data=[26, 12, 16, 27],cols=16, rows=2,auto_linebreaks=True)
lcd.cursor_pos = (0,1) 
lcd.write_string(u'WELCOME EZIMAX')
while 1:    
    lcd.cursor_pos =(1,10)
    lcd.write_string("%s" %time.strftime("%H:%M")) 
    lcd.cursor_pos = (1,0)
    lcd.write_string("%s" %time.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```

4. use this code if your connection wire is BCM
5. otherwise change code according to BOARD wire connection .

if you have again any problrm or error so follow me and contact me